# jdk1.8 GLIBC dependency issue

Tags: java, linux, java-8, glibc

I am using rhel3 with glibc-2.3.2. I am trying to migrate to jdk8 from JDK5 but getting issue with GLIBC depencency like below. Basically JDK1.7 onward, there is this dependency with GLIBC_2.4.

```
java -version
Error: dl failure on line 883
Error: failed /homes/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so, because /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /homes/JDK1.8/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so)
```

I can not install latest GLIBC in my current system, since existing glibc version is required for some other software compilation. How can I proceed ?

Comment: Uh oh, besides updating your entire linux distribution, there are ways to create an isolated environment using different libraries, but that’s more a linux administration question, entirely independent from the fact that the software in question is a JVM, so I’m suggesting redirection to [SU](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux)…

Comment: @the8472 Can you please show an example of how to use LD_PRELOAD in my context.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` is guaranteed to not work.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not install latest GLIBC in my current system, since existing glibc version is required for some other software compilation.

Are you sure? With very few exceptions (`__ctype_b` is the only one I know), newer versions of GLIBC are backward compatible (old applications continue to run with newer GLIBC versions).

> How can I proceed ?

If you *really* can't update the system glibc, you can install a newer glibc in non-default location, and make just the JDK use it.

Some of the details of how to do that are documented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Another way is to use "explicit loader invocation", like this:

```
GLIBC221LIB=/path/to/glibc-2.21/lib
$GLIBC221LIB/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path $GLIBC221LIB \
  /path/to/jdk8/bin/java ...args...
```

Yet another alternative is to upgrade the system glibc, but keep the old glibc-2.3.2 in non-default location, and point the (hopefully few) applications that are incompatible with the new glibc version to the old version.

Comment: I definitely can't update the glibc for multipe reasons. So lets keep that option out. I tried `GLIBC221LIB=/path/to/glibc-2.21/lib
$GLIBC221LIB/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path $GLIBC221LIB \
  /path/to/jdk8/bin/java ...args...`  : but get error as `FATAL: kernel too old`

Comment: @Dil Different versions of GLIBC have different minimal kernel requirements. Apparently you selected too new a version for the kernel you are running.